# Create User Quota Clause missing or invalid option

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement

Executing this statement on DBeaver or sqplus works like a charm

```
CREATE USER flyway IDENTIFIED BY password 
DEFAULT TABLESPACE system  
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE system 
QUOTA 20M on system;
```

But if I use it in java preparedstatement like this

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    //step2 create  the connection object
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "myuser", "mypassword")

    //step3 create the statement object
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    //step4 execute query
    stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE USER flyway IDENTIFIED BY password "+
            "DEFAULT TABLESPACE system  "+
            "TEMPORARY TABLESPACE system "+
            "QUOTA 20M on system;"
                            );

    //step5 close the connection object
    con.close();
```

It says
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Now if I remove  "QUOTA 20M on system" It works fine. But that quota is correct syntax so I don't get why it fails. Why can't a set a quota from java?

Comment: Remove just the semicolon. That's a statement separator, and causes errors like this when you're executing a single statement.

Comment: you are correct!

Comment: As a side observation - you should _NOT_ be creating users with default and/or temp tablespace set to SYSTEM.  That tablespace should be reserved for oracle's own use.  And you should _NEVER_ use a permanent tablespace (such as SYSTEM) as a temp TS for anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex Poole is correct POSTGRES driver works fine with the ; but the Oracle one just fails with errors that no one can understand